# IE11 memory leak when using Jquery autocomplete (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, internet-explorer, autocomplete

I have an asp.net webpage which uses Jquery autocomplete function to show a list of options on many textboxes (over >75 textboxes) by using the class="cur" on each field.

I've noticed that with every refresh of the page in IE 9-11, the memory increases by 3-5Mb every time (or even more). Once in reaches 250,000K or more, the performance is affected, everything slows down quite a lot (takes seconds to type in textboxes, refresh, etc)

If I take out the autcomplete from the page, then it works fine (hardly increases the memory of IE).

So I assume the memory leak is happening because of the jquery autocomplete function.

Find below the jquery code I am using (I've shortened the number of currency options).

So the question is, how can I avoid the memory leak while using jquery autocomplete?

UPDATE: Note that I have the jquery script within Sys.Application.add_load(function () as eitherwise it only runs the first postback, after that all autocomplete functions will stop working.

```
Sys.Application.add_load(function () {


 $('.cur').each(function () {
        var currencies = [
                                 { value: 'USA dollar', data: 'USD' },
                                 { value: 'European euro', data: 'EUR' },
                                 { value: 'South African rand', data: 'ZAR' },
                                 { value: 'Mexican peso', data: 'MXN' },
                                 { value: 'Japanese yen', data: 'JPY' },
                                 { value: 'Indian rupee', data: 'INR' },
                                 { value: 'Indonesian rupiah', data: 'IDR' },
                                 { value: 'Chinese renminbi', data: 'CNY' },
                                 { value: 'Canadian dollar', data: 'CAD' },
                                 { value: 'Brazilian real', data: 'BRL' },
                                 { value: 'Australian dollar', data: 'AUD' },
                                 { value: 'New Zealand dollar', data: 'NZD' },
                                 { value: 'Afghan afghani', data: 'AFN' },
                                 { value: 'Albanian lek', data: 'ALL' },
                                 { value: 'Vietnamese dong', data: 'VND' },
                 ...many more currencies
                                 { value: 'Yemeni rial', data: 'YER' },
                                 { value: 'Zambian kwacha', data: 'ZMK' },
                                 { value: 'Zimbabwean dollar', data: 'ZWD' },
        ];




        var txt = $(this);
        txt.autocomplete({
            source: currencies,
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function (event, ui) { $(this).val(ui.item.data); return false },
            change: function (event, ui) { $(this).trigger("change") }
        }).bind('focus', function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        })
    });

}
```

Comment: 1-.include how you are measuring the memory foot print. 2- quote "every refresh of the page" is that an F5 refresh, please clear that up for me. 3-. your saying that it doesn't happen in chrome?... what happens if you do a full page refresh... disable caching in IE in the developer options and see what happens. 4- you could change these to ajax calls instead of embedded page variables, which would drastically improve page load times and decrease page memory foot print.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. By refresh I mean postback. Everytime I press on a gridview row, update records, etc etc.  I am using Developer Tools in IE11, which now include a memory tab to check possible memory leaks, etc. It happens also in in Firefox (I don't have access to Chrome). I cannot do a full page refresh (using F5?) as this stops the page from working for various reasons and need to login again. Disable catching in IE is already on. Changing ti ajax calls will take me longer (to re-program), I was hoping to find an easier solution. Thanks.

Comment: Further more, note that I updated my question with further information about the jquery script being within Sys.Application.add_load(function () {. If it's not then only runs once. Just in case it might have something to do with that.

Comment: +1 for the question as I am also facing the jQuery auto complete leaking memory issue. I have used IE-11 development tools https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255003(v=vs.85).aspx and its leaving increased memory and objects after closing.

Answer (score 0):

Your using ASP.net

I believe your problem is more to do with ASP.net caching rather than anything to do with the javascript.

**ASP.net page caching**.

Been a while since i looked at this so cant remember the specifics.

But its something along the lines of; form post values are cached into the page.

Please confirm that it is this or is not this?

As you are working with ASP.net more than I am, If you are a veteran ASP.net user then you will know exactly what I'm on about, if not, we will have to google and dig this up...  (on my side a quick google didn't find what I was looking for).

**Update**

Google **ViewState** in asp.net, to me this is a very likely cause for what you are experiencing.

found it:
http://www.freshegg.co.uk/blog/web-design/responsive-design/creating-lean-fast-web-pages-view-state

**Update**

```
 currencies = [
     { value: 'USA dollar', data: 'USD' },
     { value: 'European euro', data: 'EUR' },
    ...many more currencies
];

Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
    $('.cur').each(function () {
            var txt = $(this);
            txt.autocomplete({
                source: currencies,
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                select: function (event, ui) { txt.val(ui.item.data); return false },
                change: function (event, ui) { txt.trigger("change") }
            }).bind('focus', function () {
                txt.autocomplete("search");
            })
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i appreciate you looking into this. I don't think it is a problem with viewstate, in fact I have checked various postbacks and the amount of viewstate data is the same....the file size that the server returns is always the same...so the problem (I think) must be somewhere else...

Comment: oh! dam... I thought i had it ;-) ill think some more.

Comment: further more the jquery/javascript code is on a separate page...which is already cached in client's computer, therefore should not be part of the aspx page being returned by server....it looks like the jquery function being applied to so many textboxes (>75) the browsers don't like it...if I turn off the jquery then the page behaves normally so (I believe) the problem must be with a jquery<>asp.net issue...

Comment: @user1135218 See answer update, also to help further i need to see where 'Sys.Application.add_load(function () {' come from or is called from